# Spring boot restTemplate connection timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, resttemplate, connection-timeout

Hello im using spring boot restTemplate to consume an api by a post request, but the call will take a long time maybe hours or days to have a response, is there a way to set the timeout connection of restTemplate to infinite for example until it gets a response or an error is thrown in the distant server.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can by using **ClientHttpRequestFactory**. You can check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) on how to do that. Or you can share your code snippet, if you have already done that but still not working. Cheers!